# Raspberry pi 6mm wide angle lens internal optics order

Tags: pi-4, camera, picamera

While playing around with the 6mm HQ camera lens I inadvertenly exposed the internal optics by unscrewing something at the back of the lens. Because I didn't know what I was doing, the optics fell down as soon as I unscrewed the back ring.

After reassembling the lens, the images now only focus in the middle and get very blurry towards the edges. This makes me believe I have reassembled the optics in the wrong order.

I haven't been able to find any information on the internet regarding the internals of the 6mm lens. Does anyone know how I should properly arrange the internal optics?

Comment: how many lens elements are there?